# background overwrites background-size

Tags: html, css

I already know the solution to my problem but I wonder why this is happening. Why background overwrites background-size? Please don't write about cross browsing.

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background: transparent url("icon.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    
}
```

**DEMO**

**http://jsfiddle.net/K74sw/2/**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`background` resets the image-position after you set size.

The reason why [is that](https://web.archive.org/web/20110610141422/https://css-infos.net/property/background):

> the ‘background’ property is a shorthand property for setting most background properties at the same place in the style sheet.

Including, `background-size`, which is the one you tried to use before.

Edited new CSS specification link: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#background

You use

```
background-size: 60px 60px;

background: transparent url("icon.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Which translates to:

```
background-size: 60px 60px;  /*You try to set bg-size*/

background-color: transparent ;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-size: auto auto; /* it resets here */
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url("icon.png");
```

So you can try using the seperate `background-...` settings

So either use:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-image: url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T3EviK7nK1s/TzEq90xiJCI/AAAAAAAABCg/OMZsUBxuMf0/s400/smilelaughuy0.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K74sw/9/

Or just swap your lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/K74sw/10/

Comment: OK that's true :) But why short version of background declaration is overwrites :) This's philosophic question.

Comment: it is in the CSS specification, and expected behavior. Not much to philosophize about ;) http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215/#the-background

Answer (score 8):

`background` is a CSS "shorthand property" for easily combining several associated background properties into one declaration (`background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-position`, etc).

Thus it overwrites any properties not directly specified in the shorthand with their default value (as far as I know... according to the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-size) you can specify `background-size` in the `background` shorthand property after `background-position` but I have not tested this and I have no idea what browser support for this is at the moment but I suspect it's not great).  As I understand it this is because the `background` shorthand implicitly sets ALL the properties it represents, not just the ones you specify, so any that are not defined in the shorthand declaration are set to their default value.

To fix it either:

1) put the `background-size` property AFTER the `background` property

2) put the `background-size` property declaration in a more specific selector i.e `a.icon` rather than `.icon`

3) don't use `background` shorthand at all but instead use the individual properties to specify

Comment: I don't need a solution of my problem, because i know how to do this. I try to understand this solution and problem. Why this is happening

Comment: I think because you did not include `background-size` in the shorthand declaration causing it to be overwritten by the default value.  See [the W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-size) for details.  This claims that `background-size` can be added in the shorthand, but I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: I added an thorough explanation. How `background` works together with `background-size`

Comment: Updated my post to reflect a little more research I did.  I am still not positive this is the explanation (i.e. unspecified shorthand properties being set to their default values and thus overriding any earlier declarations of equal or lower specificity) but it seems like the most likely explanation to me and is supported by the way the W3C describes the shorthand in their specification.

Comment: Ah yes @timmied it looks like we're giving the same explanation.

Comment: You don't need to look at the specs of `background-size` but `background`  http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215/#the-background. Which describes it in full.

Comment: Yep that's actually what I was referring to (the background shorthand is the next item below background-size in my link).

Comment: And you guessed wrong before your first edit. quote: "even though there is no place in the shorthand declaration for some of the newer CSS3 background properties" Make sure you answer right and don't guess before you answer.

Comment: That's why I edited it within about 60 seconds after looking it up and realizing I was mistaken. My bad obviously, but I should point out you come across as being grumpy you aren't scooping up 100% of the rep on this answer which is silly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be. It just annoys me sometimes wrong answers get selected as the correct one. Most of this is because people make guesses or make quick wrong answers to edit later to scoop up rep. (Your initial answer with error already had 2 rep, that's 2 people misinformed) So I was actually thinking the exact same thing about you. About scooping rep and getting a wrong answered voted. No offense

Comment: Haha that's totally fair :) it was an honest mistake though, I was actually quite surprised to find I was wrong about that. I guess I need to trust that little niggling feeling at the back of my neck that ultimately prompted me to go check on whether I was right about it more! I voted your answer up if that makes you feel a little better :P

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), there is a way to specify the size inside the `background` property, so you don't need to rely on the `background-size` at all. You can specify it like this:

```
background: url("path-to-image.svg") center/contain no-repeat
```