# Auto adjust background image using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code for uploading `background image`.

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

The script I'm using is:

```
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    $('#myframe')

                    .css({
                    background:'url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat',
                    background-size:'400px 400px'

                    });

                };

               reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);//To display images uncomment this
            }
        }
```

There is a problem.Above code works if I remove `background-size`. I want to reduce the size and resolution of the image I'm uploading. Here`$('#myframe')` is `div id` of the the area, where I want to upload. Also, let me know how do I pass `multiple` properties to `.css()` function. I tried the following code for the same, but no effect:

```
.css(background:transparent url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat,background-size:200px 300px);
```

Comment: can you create a js fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `background` is a super property and it reset `background-size`, place `background-size` after `background`.

So in your case you want:

```
$('#myframe')
    .css('background', 'transparent url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat')
    .css('background-size', '200px 300px');
```

See this post [background overwrites background-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329850/background-overwrites-background-size)

And `css` to pass multiple properties you simply pass in an object. See documentation http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I tried this
 $('#myframe')
      .css('background-size','100px 30px')
      .css('background', 'transparent url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat');

Comment: both the .css are applied to same selector #myframe still not showing

Comment: @MS Wachasunder Yeah it's another issue, already resolved somewhere updated answer with info and the link

Comment: I think you cannot pass `e.target.result` to background property

Comment: try using a img tag instead

Comment: No @waqarmirza removing the background-size it works perfectly. Except the problem to resize persists

Comment: `e.target.result` is fine it's the FileReader API http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/15/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-2/ and using an `<img>` as background is opening a can of worms.

Comment: @gillesc I edited the question as per your advice but still no effect.

Comment: Have you tried with pure HTML CSS? Is `background` before `background-size` in the style attribute of the element?

Comment: @gillesc here is the link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size they have used background before background-size.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kHqLE/2/

The output from `e.target.result` is not an image object, its a raw string.

Comment: .Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/mithilesh18/Dj6mg/1/ and here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227027/background-as-color-and-background-as-image