# Background as color and background as image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question is a bit lengthy, but all of it is related so I am putting them here.I am trying this since past 2 days and i am  very close of getting a solution.But something is wrong in css or scripting code can't understand where.

Following is the fiddle link I received as a response to my question [click here to view](http://jsfiddle.net/kHqLE/2/)
You can view my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219280/auto-adjust-background-image-using-css) .

In order to test it I simply copied and pasted the code as given in the link and saved as demo.html. The contents are exactly this:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>File API - FileReader (Text)</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
        <label for="files">Select a file: </label>
        <input id="files" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" /><br>
        div<div id="result"></div><br>
        img<img src='' id="img"><br>
    </article>
    <script>
    var readURL;
window.onload = function() {

    //Check File API support
    readURL = function(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function (tFile) {
                    return function (evt) {
                      //$('#img').attr('src', evt.target.result);

                        $('#result').css({'background-image': 'url('+evt.target.result+')','background-size': '200px 200px', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position':'center'})
                    };
                  }(input.files[0]));
               reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Problem-1 is that image is not showing up.I simply can't understand why?

Problem-2:
 Next with code posted in my previous question [you can view here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219280/auto-adjust-background-image-using-css). I am at least able to set the background. But not resize the background image even if I use background-size after background or irrespective of the property-value pair in quotes or not.I have accepted the answer because fiddle was working,but problem is still unresolved. Is it that  .css() function of jQuery is not taking multiple values well in that case [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHqLE/2/)
must also not work. But its working.

Problem-3:
Another  point of interest is switching the background image on-click multiple times like for eg. onclick of button for red background changes to red but onclick of upload image is uploaded and background becomes image. Now I have implemented both in single page.I can show you the code on request.Problem is once I set image as background I cannot simply change it back to color. Note the script of color change in the background is before image change script.

You can choose to answer any of the problem according to your expertise.  Any help or links or research will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example of where the image is not showing up?

Comment: @webkit ok here is the link to fiddle not working
http://jsfiddle.net/mithilesh18/Dj6mg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this style for it to work:

```
#result {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You also need to add query:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried this but no result.
        div<div id="result" style="height: 300px;
    width: 100%;"></div><br>

Comment: I copied the exact code from above in your question and it's working fine. What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/h6Qaf/1/

Comment: I think it's not working because you didn't add query. See my answer above

Comment: what is no wrap in head

Comment: onLoad:
wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window event

onDomReady:
wrap the code so it will run in onDomReady window event

no wrap - in <head>:
do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <head> section

no wrap - in <body>:
do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <body> section

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem..

I didn't dig why exactly your fiddle had an error of 'readURL' is undefined
but since you used jquery, I attached the event and called it with jquery
and now it works:

```
$(function () {
    $("#files").on('change', readURL);
});

//Check File API support
function readURL() {
    var input = this;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (tFile) {
            return function (evt) {
                //$('#img').attr('src', evt.target.result);

                $('#result').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')', 'background-size': '200px 200px', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position': 'center' })
            };
        }(input.files[0]));
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dj6mg/2/)

Comment: The error in the fiddle of 'readURL' is undefined is because you need to set the jQuery framework to No wrap in body instead of onload

Comment: If you'd like help with problems 2 & 3.. please make it easier and post the exact issue to a fiddle like you did for 1..